# How does Poetry work regarding binary dependencies? (esp. numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda, python-poetry

Until now I have been using conda as virtual environment and dependency management. However, some stuff does not work as expected when transfering my environment.yml file from my development machine to the production server. Now, I would like to look into alternatives. Poetry seems nice, especially because

> poetry also maintains a lock file, and it has a benefit over pipenv because it keeps track of which packages are subdependencies. (https://realpython.com/effective-python-environment/#poetry)

which might improve stability quite a bit. However, I am working on [science-heavy projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) (matrices, data science, machine learning), so in practise I need the scipy stack (e.g. numpy, pandas, scitkit-learn).

> Python became too slow for some pure computational workloads so numpy and scipy were born. [...] They are written in C and just wrapped as a python library.
>
> Compiling such libraries brings a set of challenges since they (more or less) have to be compiled on your machine for maximum performance and proper linking with libraries like glibc.
>
> Conda was introduced as an all-in-one solution to manage python environments for the scientific community.
>
> [...] Instead of using a fragile process of compiling libraries on your machine, libraries are precompiled and just downloaded when you request them. Unfortunately, the solution comes with a caveat - conda does not use PyPI, the most popular index of python packages.
>
> (https://modelpredict.com/python-dependency-management-tools#fnref:conda-compiling-challenges)

As far as I know, this doesn't even do Conda justice, because it does quite a bit of optimization to get the most out of my CPU/GPU/architecture for numpy. (https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/#Myth-#6:-Now-that-pip-uses-wheels,-conda-is-no-longer-necessary)

https://numpy.org/install/ itself advises to use conda, but also says that one can install via pip (and poetry uses pypi)

> For users who know, from personal preference or reading about the main differences between conda and pip below, they prefer a pip/PyPI-based solution, we recommend:
>
> [...] Use Poetry as the most well-maintained tool that provides a dependency resolver and environment management capabilities in a similar fashion as conda does.

I would like to get the stability of the poetry setup and the speed of the conda setup.

**How does poetry handle binary dependencies?
Does it also, like conda, consider my hardware?**

If poetry not deliver in this regard, can I combine it with conda?

Comment: Whoever voted for closing... could you PLEASE give a reason?

Comment: Poetry is pip-side answer to conda, but I think hard to get a specific recipe for your project without actually trying. You may want to review pipenv too, but it had issues in the last release.

Comment: Choice of specific tools is not favored on SO, so that is why someone asked to close.

Comment: @Evgeny: Fair enough, but I did not ask for a choice of tools! I rephrased the question slightly to make that even more clear: I am asking how poetry works and then I ask how I can combine it with conda.

Comment: Just my guess about any closing vote, I personally upvoted a question. WIth new headline it is much better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numpy` provides several `wheel` files for different os, cpu architecture and python versions. `wheel` packages are precompiled, so the target system doesn't have to compile the package.

`poetry` is able to choose the right wheel for you, depending on your system.

Saying this, I would recommend using `poetry`, as long as you just need python packages, which are also available at pypi. As soon as you need other, non-python tools, stick to conda. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainer of `poetry`).

Also related: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1904

Comment: Is poetry also optimizing the choice of the right wheel by considering whether to use Intel MKL,OpenBLAS, or BLIS? (see last section in https://numpy.org/install/) Does poetry also track the version of the binaries? I am asking, because https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/#Myth-#6:-Now-that-pip-uses-wheels,-conda-is-no-longer-necessary says it does not.

Comment: As there are no wheels on pypi specific for the criteria you mention - and AFAIK there is no standard on how to describe them - poetry isn't able to do this by design.

Comment: Which of my questions are you answering, a) the one regarding Intel MKL,OpenBLAS, or BLIS or b) the one regarding version tracking?

Comment: My answer was for question a) :) Not sure what you mean by version tracking? If you mean, having a history when which package was installed/updated/removed: No, this is not included in poetry. Something similar is possible by putting the poetry.lock in a git repository along with the package data.

Comment: After revisiting https://numpy.org/install/, it seems my answer is the paragraph "The NumPy wheels on PyPI, which is what pip installs, are built with OpenBLAS. The OpenBLAS libraries are shipped within the wheels itself. This makes those wheels larger, and if a user installs (for example) SciPy as well, they will now have two copies of OpenBLAS on disk." Since poetry uses PyPI, this should answer my question: Using Poetry results in using OpenBLAS (which is slower than Intel MKL). But I read there are also packages for Intel MKL on PyPI. I have to look into it more.

Comment: A question: if I use poetry in a conda environment, how will it handle packages already installed with conda? Does it take those into account when solving dependencies? Could we visualise that? I prefer to let poetry handle the solving, but prefer conda to install numpy and scipy...

Comment: @finswimmer how can you tell `poetry` to install the binary wheels on pypi instead of compiling from source when installing `numpy`? When I run `poetry add numpy` it always compiles from source rather than installing the wheels. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On MAC Os BigSur (11.1)

I've being facing issues all day with numpy failing install (with pandas) for Python 3.9.1.6 and poetry 1.1.4.

I understood that poetry uses pip which does not use the wheel version of numpy when pip <= 20.2.x. And fresh installation of Python 3.9.1.6 does not upgrade pip !

This is how I managed to install what I needed :

First check the default version of Python linked to poetry (reinstall it if it does not fit)

```sh
poetry env info | grep -i python
Python:         3.9.1
Implementation: CPython
Python:   /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

Install you project and run `poetry init` without any dependencies you seek (you'll use `poetry add <deps>` juste after...)

You should obtain something similar to this pyproject.toml :

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "project1"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [""]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Launch the poetry shell

```sh
➜  project1 poetry shell

Python 2.7 will no longer be supported in the next feature release of Poetry (1.2).
You should consider updating your Python version to a supported one.

Note that you will still be able to manage Python 2.7 projects by using the env command.
See https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/ for more information.

Spawning shell within /Users/vincent/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project1-5XOg8Qie-py3.9
➜  project1 . /Users/vincent/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project1-5XOg8Qie-py3.9/bin/activate
(project1-5XOg8Qie-py3.9) ➜  project1
```

***At this point*** upgrade pip, wheel and setuptools !

```sh
(project1-5XOg8Qie-py3.9) ➜  project1 $ pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-51.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel, setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.4
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.4
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.35.1
    Uninstalling wheel-0.35.1:
      Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.35.1
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 50.3.2
    Uninstalling setuptools-50.3.2:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-50.3.2
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3 setuptools-51.1.2 wheel-0.36.2
```

Now installation should be ok

```sh
(project1-5XOg8Qie-py3.9) ➜  project1 poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing six (1.15.0)
  - Installing numpy (1.19.5)
  - Installing python-dateutil (2.8.1)
  - Installing pytz (2020.5)
  - Installing pandas (1.2.0)

Installing the current project: project1 (0.1.0)
```

Yeepee !