# How to use NumPy+MKL with Poetry?

Tags: python, numpy, package-managers, intel-mkl, python-poetry

I'd like to include [NumPy+MKL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) as a dependency in my project. It seems that the main options for publishing tools are setuptools, Poetry, and Anaconda.

I'd like to use Poetry. I'm already familiar with it; it's a very nice packaging solution. It was made to eliminate the complexities experienced with setuptools. I haven't explored Anaconda much, and if Poetry doesn't work for my package I'll probably try it.

I know that Poetry [looks for wheel files on PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513525/7232335) and doesn't currently have plans [to support other "channels"](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1904) like Anaconda does. So there's no way in `pyproject.toml` to specify something like:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = "1.21.1+mkl"
```

But there is one feature of Poetry that looks promising: [url dependencies](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#url-dependencies). It seems if there were a URL for the NumPy+MKL package I wanted to include, I could specify:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = { url = "https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/numpy‑1.21.1+mkl‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl" }
```

And that's exactly what I'd like to do, except there doesn't seem to be an existing URL that works for this purpose. (When I try the above address, I get a "Secure Connection Failed" error in Firefox.)

**Am I thinking about this problem correctly? Does anyone know of a URL I can specify in `pyproject.toml`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheels available on [Christoph Gohlke's site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) are for personal use only, and are **not** meant for distribution. His page is not a `pip` repository, which is why he makes heavy use of Javascript URL obfuscation to download the files. `numpy==1.21.1+mkl` is not a valid version identifier.

I think you may also be misunderstanding what exactly the MKL builds are. They use the same base code as the [regular NumPy package](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) from PyPI - there's nothing different about them except for the fact that the C and Fortran parts are linked against [Intel's Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl.html), giving some speed advantages in some situations. They're not magical, they don't implement any new functions, there's nothing different about it except the speed factor, which typically isn't that noticeable except when using very large datasets anyways.

If your users want to use the MKL-linked version of NumPy, they'll already know about it and know how to install it independent of your package. All your package needs is a regular NumPy dependency for the minimum version that meets your code's requirements.

Comment: Ah, yes. It seems [NumPy also notifies](https://numpy.org/install/) that packages are not meant to be distributed with NumPy+MKL: "Intel MKL is not open source. For normal use this is not a problem, but if a user needs to redistribute an application built with NumPy, this could be an issue."

Comment: @NathanielJones yes, that is correct as well. The "oneMKL" *interface* is open-source, but the actual library is not. IANAL, but this likely means it wouldn't play well with GPL code, and probably other licenses as well.

Comment: What about on the install end of things? It seems Poetry can still be useful for publishing a package that uses NumPy+MKL - just include NumPy as a dependency. Sounds good. But if I `pip install` a C. Gohlke NumPy+MKL, then when I run `poetry install` to get the rest of the dependencies (my published package included), it wants to "update" it with regular NumPy. Do I have to use pip exclusively then? Seems like that detracts from the usefulness of Poetry's dependency management abilities.